# Tab Indicators Obscured by android:background

Tags: android

Simple `TabLayout`. No tab indicator. Arggh!

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_tabs"
    style="@style/MyTabLayout"
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabMinWidth">100dp</item>
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">100dp</item>
    <item name="tabIndicator">@drawable/tab_indicator_rounded_top_corners</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">5dp</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorFullWidth">false</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/color_accent_dark</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

tab_indicator_rounded_top_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is what pops out. There should be a white bar under the selected tab.

I am almost sure that this relates to this line in the theme overlay:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
```

Because when I do not override the background color, I can see the tab indicators. Problem is that I need to change that background color in some cases using theme overlays.

[image]

Comment: Which version of material components are you using?

Comment: Facing the same problem, did you get the solution?